# How to remove an element from a list with a case_when

Tags: r

I have a nested list of strings and I want to enter a value in a new column when a grepl condition is met and I also want to remove that element from the nested list

My list is as follows (nested within a dataframe)

```
list( "Normal Mucosa Throughout", "Mitotic Lesion- See Text Above", 
    "Normal", 
    c("Mitotic", "Hiatus Hernia"), "Normal Mucosa Throughout", 
    "HALO RFA to Barrett's oesophagus", "Barretts oesophagus", 
    c("Barrett's oesophagus ", "EMR"))
```

The desired result:

```
FindingsAfterProcessing                  DiagnosisCode             
Normal Mucosa Throughout                 other  
                                         C159
Normal                                   other
 Hiatus Hernia                           C159
Normal Mucosa Throughout                 other
HALO RFA to Barrett's oesophagus         other
Barretts oesophagus                      other
Barrett's oesophagus                     other
                                         EMR
```

My `case_when`

```
 myDf<-myDf%>%   
    mutate(DiagnosisCode             = case_when( 
        grepl("mitotic|emr",tolower(myDf$OriginalFindings),ignore.case=TRUE) ~  "C159  -  Malignant neoplasm oesophagus, unspecified - Oesophagus - unspecified",
        TRUE                      ~  "other")
    )
```

How do I apply this to a nested list and also remove the element once found?

Comment: It would help if you provided an short example of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try `map` from `purrr` (you can also just load `tidyverse`):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    DiagnosisCode = map(
      FindingsAfterProcessing, ~ case_when(
        any(grepl("mitotic", tolower(.x))) ~ "C159",
        any(grepl("emr", tolower(.x))) ~ "EMR",
        TRUE ~ "other")
      ),
    FindingsAfterProcessing = map(
      FindingsAfterProcessing, ~ .x[!grepl("mitotic|emr", tolower(.x))]
      )
  )
```

The output here would be:

```
           FindingsAfterProcessing DiagnosisCode
1         Normal Mucosa Throughout         other
2                                           C159
3                           Normal         other
4                    Hiatus Hernia          C159
5         Normal Mucosa Throughout         other
6 HALO RFA to Barrett's oesophagus         other
7              Barretts oesophagus         other
8            Barrett's oesophagus            EMR
```

This does not 100% correspond to your desired output, but I guess there is a typo in your output?

I'm saying this because my output is on the basis of the list you have provided; I've turned it into a dataframe column:

```
df <- data.frame(FindingsAfterProcessing = I(list( "Normal Mucosa Throughout", "Mitotic Lesion- See Text Above", 
                                  "Normal", 
                                  c("Mitotic", "Hiatus Hernia"), "Normal Mucosa Throughout", 
                                  "HALO RFA to Barrett's oesophagus", "Barretts oesophagus", 
                                  c("Barrett's oesophagus ", "EMR"))))
```